# Node.js Install Problems on Windows

Tags: node.js, discord

I am trying to code a discord Bot.

When i install Node.js to Path, Everything seems fine. However, then i go to Visual Studio Code, type in terminal `npm init` and this error comes up:

> - npm init
> - ~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I am not sure how to interpret or fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, 
it's a problem that a lot of users like you have. There are no 3000 solutions for this. The easiest way (and the one I would recommend) is to use the manual installation method available at https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows
If the problem persists, I invite you to try to reinstall Nodejs and take the last available version (here 9.3.0)
https://nodejs.org/en/